# Unfamiliar Notation in Sum; Encountered in AdaBoost description

Tags: summation, notation, statistical-inference

While trying to understand the relation between AdaBoost and Forward Stagewise Additive Modeling, I came across the following notation:

$$
G_m = arg \min_{b \in H} \sum_{i=1}^n w_i^{(t)} I_{y_i \neq b(x_i)}
$$

I do not understand what $$ I_{y_i \neq b(x_i)} $$ looks like. Is it a square matrix with ones on the diagonal except where $y_i = b(x_i)$?

I hope someone who has seen this notation before can explain this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It's the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).